# Can't locate a python script from error message

Tags: python, build, egg

I am trying to trace the origin of a python error message that I am getting when I try to run my code `test.py`.

The module (which is called by `test.py`) that I am trying to trace from the error output is apparently:

```
build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/george/gp.py
```

The error message snippet:

```
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/george/gp.py", line 498, in
    predict
```

1. I can find `build/bdist.linux-x86_64/` but it is empty. Maybe it's not the 'right one'.
2. I have also found a different version of `gp.py`, but when I make changes to that, nothing happens, so `test.py` is not calling that version.

All I want to do is find the code in which the error is occurring so that I can add some more outputs to it to figure out what is going wrong.

---

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 213, in <module>
    mumc, dummy = gp1.predict(residuals, dates, kernel = kernelprime )
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/george/gp.py", line 511, in predict
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/george/solvers/basic.py", line 87, in apply_inverse
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp_cholesky.py", line 174, in cho_solve
    b1 = asarray_chkfinite(b)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1219, in asarray_chkfinite
"array must not contain infs or NaNs")
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

So obviously, at some point down the line, I am feeding an array that contains infs or NaNs into some scipy or numpy code that it doesn't like. But to see why the values are infs or NaNs in the first place, it seems like whatever is going wrong is happening in the `predict` module.

(gp1 is a class which is also defined in the `gp.py` code!)

Comment: Are you sure that your error is in "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/george/gp.py"? It is a rather deep system file. Maybe something else is causing the error in your code?

Comment: Check where the error origins, that is usually the cause.

Comment: Yes, please include the entire error traceback please

Comment: Okay I have added the error message to my original post, thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but it looks like your infinity/NaN is generated because you have a zero value in a covariance matrix (and hence, the covariance matrix is non-invertible).  With regard to finding the correct version, you should be able to get an absolute path to the module with `george.__file__`, which should help give you a better idea where the active file is located.

Comment: I think you are right about the zeros; the values are usually very small anyway e.g. 1e-17, but they can get smaller. I guess that they must be going smaller that 1e-324 (or whatever the smallest number python handles) and getting set to 0.0?

Comment: I tried the george.__file__ thing, but it just returns: 

/home/pbrook/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/george-0.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/george/__init__.pyc

But this doesn't help because the part ending .egg is not a directory

Answer (score 4):

Python stores the source file path in the byte-compiled versions of modules when compiling those to Python byte code. Those byte-compiled versions are normally generated „on the fly“ and re-used automatically.

Your program inadvertently uses a `gp.pyc` file somewhere in the tree, that was compiled from the `gp.py` in the `build/...` path you see. Normally, `build/` is only used when packages are built. I suspect you somehow messed things up when building the `george` egg.

Check for `.pyc` files in you Python path  and remove those. They‘ll be rebuilt automatically (given the real `.py` files are found).

For example from you project directory:

```
$ find . -name `*.pyc` -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: @user1551817 This answer seems to be correct, If does help you, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can see what file is actually loaded by using the `.__file__` attribute on the module, or by calling `inspect.getfile()`.

Your example doesn't mention, but you're likely importing `gp` or `gp1` in your `test.py`. You could try:

```
import gp
import inspect

print(gp.__file__)
print(inspect.getfile(gp))
```

Both lines should show you what file was actually loaded from Python's perspective and should allow you to track down the file with the issue.